# Iterate through elements with similar IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the `id` of a single `<span>` element during iteration.

Example scenario:

I have a few `id`s which start with `AAA` and end with `BBB`. The middle characters can vary:

```
 <span id="AAA-LS-BBB">hi1</span>
 <span id="AAA-LAS-BBB">hi2</span>
 <span id="AAA-LBS-BBB">hi3</span>
 <span id="AAA--LCS--BBB">hi4</span>
```

Here, first 3 digits of span id and last 3 digits of span id is same...only in middle it will vary. I want to generalized method to know ...each id using... $("#id").attr("id")
so, here
 I am trying to find out iteration like below,
I want to write one iterator method to get the current id

```
$("span[id^='AAA-***-BBB']").each(function(){
    var a = $("this").attr("id");
});
```

Hope my requirements are clear.
how ti use regular expression here.. to find out id?

Comment: What do you mean with print? How? Where?

Comment: Uhh, quite unclear I must say. Either use [jsfiddle.net](jsfiddle.net) or update your post with at the very least some HTML and a clearer description of what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `.filter()` combined with a regex:

```
$('span[id]').filter(function () {
    return /^AAA.*BBB$/.test(this.id);
}).each(function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Alternatively, since you are using a `.each()` already, you can simply add an `if` condition inside it:

```
$('span[id]').each(function () {
    if (/^AAA.*BBB$/.test(this.id)) {
        alert(this.id);
    }
});
```

---

**Update**: It looks like you can also combine both the [Attribute-Starts-With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [Attribute-Ends-With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selectors on the same attribute:

```
$('div[id^="AAA"][id$="BBB"]').each(function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

(See example: http://jsfiddle.net/2pz8X/)

Answer (score 0):

Combining fellow contributors' suggestions, and making the regex more specific:

`// first, at least get all <div>'s with id's that start with 'AAA'
$("div[id^='AAA']").filter(function(){ 
    var regexp = /^A{3}(.*)B{3}$/; // regex
    return (this.id.match(regexp));
});`

This will return all the div's that you need to target.

Sample @ http://jsfiddle.net/4ZNWJ/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("span[id^='AAA']").each(function(){
  alert($(this).id);
});
```

Comment: This does not work. $(this) is undefined. You need to use `this.id` instead.